# How to build the "sed" command, in Linux Bash (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, bash, sed, cron

I'm struggling to create a command line to replace `"00-59/1 * * * *"` with `"11-11/1 * * * *"`. Actually, both value will be passed through variables, once those values change according to the user behavior.

`var1="00-59/1 * * * *"`

`var2="11-11/1 * * * *"`

As you can see, those values belong to crontab. This is a script to change the schedule value on crontab.

I do know that the big issue here is because there is "/" caracter inside, but I couldn't figure out how to make it works.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please add expected output to post with code tags.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a example input.

```
$ cat input 
00-59/1 * * * * TASK1
* * * * * TASK2
00 1 * * * TASK3
1 1 1 1 1 TASK4

# Escaping `#` and `\` before substitute. 
# For BSD Sed
$ var1="$(echo "00-59/1 * * * *" | sed -E 's/([/*])/\\\1/g')"
$ var2="$(echo "11-11/1 * * * *" | sed -E 's/([/*])/\\\1/g')"

# For GNU Sed
$ var1="$(echo "00-59/1 * * * *" | sed -r 's/([/*])/\\\1/g')"
$ var2="$(echo "11-11/1 * * * *" | sed -r 's/([/*])/\\\1/g')"

# Don't forget to use double quotes. :)
$ cat input | sed "s/${var1}/${var2}/"
11-11/1 * * * * TASK1
* * * * * TASK2
00 1 * * * TASK3
1 1 1 1 1 TASK4
```